# Age distribution by gender using MongoDB's aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have several thousand documents in a MongoDB collection named `customers` and all of them have the same schema:

```
{ 
  "gender" : "male", 
  "age" : NumberInt(34)
}
{ 
  "gender" : "female", 
  "age" : NumberInt(56)
}
{ 
  "gender" : "male", 
  "age" : NumberInt(48)
}
... and so on
```

I want to analyse all these documents and generate a basic demographic report which looks something like this:

[image: Demographic report]

I was able to group the customers by age using `$bucket` but I don't know how I can integrate gender into my pipeline.  Is there any way to get the data I require in MongoDB using the aggregation framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$bucket` you need to write a `$cond`ition to get male, female and total count

```
db.g.aggregate([
{
    $bucket:
    {
        groupBy : "$age", 
        boundaries:[0,20,30,40,50], 
        default:"other", 
        output : 
            {
                "total" : {$sum : 1}, 
                "male" : {$sum : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$gender", "male" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}},
                "female" : {$sum : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$gender", "female" ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }}}  }
            }
    }
])
```

output

```
{ "_id" : 30, "total" : 1, "male" : 1, "female" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 40, "total" : 1, "male" : 1, "female" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "other", "total" : 1, "male" : 0, "female" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.